# actionPerformed from an array

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jcombobox

My Java `JComboBox` is made up array for loop

Assume that combo box is will list:

```
"Argentina Vs USA" // array[0]
"Brazil Vs Canada" // array[1]
"Canada Vs Netherland" // array[2]
"Holland Vs Netherland" // array[3]
```

Then once an option is chosen in the..

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
String countryVScountry = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
//I need help here, I don't want to get the String, but the 
//array number instead.
//e.g. I choose "Brazil Vs Canada"
//What method should I use to make it return "1"?
//then if I choose "Holland Vs Netherland", it will return 3
}
```

I don't want to get the String, but the  array number instead.
e.g. I choose "Brazil Vs Canada"

- What method should I use to make it return "1"?
- Then if I choose "Holland Vs Netherland", it will return 3

Comment: Holland vs. Netherlands?

Comment: gratz for pointing that out! haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) rather than `getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: lol, thank you very much, and sorry for the stupid question that I made. Should have study more first. Thank you once again